# Email disappears in OWA

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

i have an hosted exchange 2013 server, with 2 emails address configured in POP on thunderbird.

But my email disappears in OWA after reading them in thunderbird.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a fairly common thing for a POP3 client to delete the mail off the upstream host once it's successfully downloaded the messages. This is usually a configurable option. Look at your Thunderbird preferences for that account.

There may be some server side POP3 configuration options too, but this is typically a client configurable behavior.

Comment: Typically that's the main reason why as the user you should want to use IMAP for mail clients, not only does that leave mail stored on the server by default, you can access the other folders stored on the server besides the Inbox, and have messages sent through Thunderbird copied to the same Sent items OWA uses for a single archive.

Answer (score 4):

You should configure Thunderbird with ExQuilla instead: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/connect-the-thunderbird-email-client-to-your-exchange-server/

But like SpacemanSpiff said if you are adamant about using POP, then in Thunderbird:

1. Select Tools / Account Settings.
2. Under your email account, click the Server Settings link.
3. In the Server Settings section, check the `Leave messages on server` box.
4. Click the OK button.